# Cart Initialized in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just have a question, when i should initialized cart in Vues?
beforeMount or Mounted? (I think, beforeMount)

```
<div v-if='isCartInitialized'>
  <div v-for='(item, index) in item.warehouse_positions' :key='index'>
    <button> buy </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
 <spinner size='medium' class='product-offer__control' style='margin-top: 0;'></spinner>
</div>
```

Have a problem that the spinner is constantly loading without showing the "Buy" button. I think if moving the initialization to beforemount might solve the problem?

```
beforeMount() {
 if (!this.isCartInitialized) {
   this.initializeCart();
 }
},
```

**state**:

```
state: {
 uuid: null,
 items: [],
 sections: [],
 phone: null,
 isSending: false,
 coupon: null,
 lastAddedProduct: false,
 isNotificationActive: false
},
```

**initializeCart** function:

```
    initializeCart: ({ commit }) => {
  cartService.initialize().then(({ data: { cartUuid, items, sections, coupon } }) => {
    commit('initCart', { uuid: cartUuid, items, sections, coupon });
  });
},
```

Comment: @Alex nowhere in your code we see where `isCartInitialized` is being stored...

Comment: @null sorry, im new with vue... Maybe ```isCartInitialized: ({ uuid }) => !!uuid,``` this is in a ```getters```

Comment: if you put `{{isCartInitialized}}` in your template, what does it show?